# What types of kills don't count for "I have minions for that"?

Tags: achievements, titan-quest-anniversary-edition

What types of kills don't count for "I have minions for that", the "Finish Normal with less than 100 monsters killed" Steam Achievement.

[A Guide](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=773087425) says:

> Finish Normal with less than 100 monsters killed by yourself with normal LeftMouseButton attacks or any skills. This means that you have to select masteries which let you summoning pets (Spirit, Earth, Nature etc.). Only the pets are allowed to kill enemies. Trap kills (like in Rogue) are also fine.

---

But can I get kills from other sources without locking myself out of the achievement, like a "Shrine of Thorns", which gives "Bleeding Retaliation"?

Or Poison and other Damage over Time?

---

Are the different kill types stored differently in the save files, and can be checked that way?

Or do Minion kills not get recorded in the stats menu, and that's how we know?

Note: They do indeed not get noted...

Answer (score 1):

> What types of kills don't count

Kills made by your minions/pets and kills made by other players in multiplayer mode.

The easiest/fastest way to complete this is to do it with another player who has the Hades waypoint and have him kill Hades for you.

Answer (score 0):

Minion kills don't count for the kill counter, so the answer seems to be "any kills that don't raise the kill count".

Meaning "of Thorns" and poison both don't work for the achievement.